# How do I modify the bootstrap carousel javascript file so that it can trigger this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(".carousel-inner img").load(function(){
    var pic_height = $(this).height();
    var should_height = $(this).parents('.item').height();
    var pad = (should_height - pic_height ) / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-top',pad);
});
```

This function uses javascript to vertically center the image to its parent div.

I tried doing this immediately after `.carousel()`. However, I realize that only the first image gets vertically centered, and the rest of them get screwed up because the images haven't "loaded" yet (therefore making pic_height 0).

My solution is to call this function immediately after the carousel goes to the next slide.

However, I'm unfamiliar with the bootstrap javascript file.  Where do I add this function? How do I make it trigger this function?

I do **not** want a css solution.   Because of my requirements in css, a pure css solution will not work. (I have tried every trick in the book for pure css vertical align, but my situation won't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could position each images on dom ready like this :

```
$(".carousel-inner img").each(function(i, e){
    var pic_height = $(e).height();
    var should_height = $(e).parents('.item').height();
    var pad = (should_height - pic_height ) / 2;
    $(e).css('margin-top',pad);
});
```

If you want to trigger it on slide, bootstrap carousel provides the following events :

> - slide : This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is
>     invoked.
> - slid : This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

Translated to jQuery it'll be :

```
$('.carousel').on('slide', function(e) { /* your code */ });
```